# Javascript resize base64 image

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have a function that send a base64 image to my input, but I want to resize the image before send to input. I need a 250x250 image, but when take shot from mobile the image goes 3096x3096...

There is my code:

```js
function sendPhoto() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();

    FR.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      var permitted_files = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/bmp'];
      var baseImg = e.target.result;
      var parteImg = baseImg.substring(11, 15);

      if (parteImg.includes('jpeg') || parteImg.includes('png') || parteImg.includes('bmp')) {
        document.getElementById('sendedPhoto').src = e.target.result;
        document.getElementById('btnPhoto').style.display = '';
      } else {
        $('body').overhang({
          type: 'error',
          message: 'This is not an image file.',
        });
        document.getElementById('uploadFoto').value = '';
      }
    });

    FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: As you know, base64 is an encoding.  It ISN'T an image format.  To resize the image, you'll need to 1) find a JS image manipulation library, 2) decode the base64 text to binary, 3) pass the binary image to your library and resize it.  NOTE: If you're displaying this in an HTML <img> tag, maybe it would be easier to set the height/width attributes?

Comment: Can you just set the width/height attributes when you display it? Why the need to resize it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Canvas to do that [Refer : Canvas Image](https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/resize.html)